# I need to make this graph in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, graph

Hello I need to make this graph that is shown in the image, in flutter. Can somebody help me. I have not been able to modify any of the ones that come by default to achieve it. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a repository which provides "Gauge Charts" out of the box:

Repository:
https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter

Available charts:
https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html

Maybe it fits your requirement

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are looking for. Have you tried **Syncfusion Flutter Gauges**?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_gauges/gauges.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: GaugeWidget(
              title: 'Now producing',
              unit: 'kW',
              minimum: 0,
              maximum: 4,
              value: 1.1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class GaugeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String unit;
  final double minimum;
  final double maximum;
  final double value;

  const GaugeWidget({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.unit,
    this.minimum,
    this.maximum,
    this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfRadialGauge(
      title: GaugeTitle(
          text: title,
          textStyle:
              const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      axes: <RadialAxis>[
        RadialAxis(
          minimum: minimum,
          maximum: maximum,
          ranges: <GaugeRange>[
            GaugeRange(
                startValue: minimum, endValue: value, color: Colors.green),
            GaugeRange(
                startValue: value,
                endValue: maximum,
                color: Colors.transparent),
          ],
          pointers: <GaugePointer>[NeedlePointer(value: value)],
          annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
            GaugeAnnotation(
                widget: Container(
                    child: Text('$value$unit',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                angle: 90,
                positionFactor: 0.5)
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> **Disclaimer:** This is a commercial package. To use their packages, you need to have either the Syncfusion Commercial License or Syncfusion Community license (FREE if your business has a gross revenue of less than $1,000,000.00 USD per year and less than 5 developers).

---

Now, if your objective is to have a gauge that looks exactly like the one portrayed in your screenshot...

[image]

...I would recommend hiring a Freelance Flutter developer to perform the task.

---

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges